# Ubuntu server 12.04.5 Package php5-mcrypt is not available

Tags: server, 12.04

I'm on Ubuntu Server 12.04.5
I'm trying to install php5-mcrypt. I'm getting this error.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mcrypt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first add the Universe repository to install `php5-mcrypt` -

Ubuntu 12.04 and below -

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Ubuntu 12.10 and above -

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Update your software lists -

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the package `php5-mcrypt` -

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

---

In case the `add-apt-repository` command is not recognized, run the following command -

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Comment: You were right,    add-apt-repository was not found 
I ran    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common but still getting same error

Comment: I stopped after $ sudo add-apt-repository universe command not found
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common was not effective

Comment: Got another error: 
sudo add-apt-repository universe 
Error: 'universe' invalid

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry to bother again, I installed a new server on a VM to try this from a fresh install. I couldn't run apt-get install python-software-properties
I got the same error I was getting for php5-mcrypt!!! Sounds like an endless loop now
I cannot run sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe" because I need to run apt-get install python-software-properties first!

Comment: Are you still using Ubuntu 12.04 on the new VM?

Comment: You know I just tried the installation, everything is working normally like the bug never existed! Someone must have fixed the bug